# Change an image during a month

Tags: javascript, html

I want a certain logo to show up during a month. I tried the following but it never worked. One is a gif and the other is a PNG.

Javascript:

```js
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

const refreshStatus = () => {
  // Get dates/time/hours
  let today = new Date(); //today date

  //Show available if this matches
  if (today.getMonth == 5) {
    logo.src='../../img/logo2.gif';
  } else {
    logo.src='../../img/logo.png';
  }
}

// run when starting
refreshStatus();

// updates every 8 seconds
setInterval(refreshStatus, 8000);
```

HTML:

```html
<a href="../index.html" class="index-link"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" id="logo"></a>
<script src="js/pride.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show complete code, not just fragments.

Comment: `today.getMonth` or `today.getMonth()` ?

Comment: @E.Maggini You don't need more code to solve this problem, they've provided a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) for it is a function (or more specifically a method on `Date.prototype`). Currently you are comparing a function to a number, which is never true.

```
if (today.getMonth() == 5) { // ...
```